# adding list to request's parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am uploading an image to the local server with following function;

```
uploadPhoto() {
    let ft = new Transfer();
    let filename = this.imagePath.substr(this.imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    let options = {
      fileKey: 'file',
      fileName: filename,
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
      chunkedMode: false,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': undefined,
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
      },
      params: {
        fileName: filename,
        users: this.user_list,
        name: this.event_name,
        event_type: this.event_type,
        date: this.date,
        start: this.timeStarts,
        location: this.location,
        info: this.description
      }
    };
    alert(options);
    ft.upload(this.imagePath, UPLOAD_URL, options, true)
      .then((result: any) => {
        this.imageChosen = 0;
        this.imagePath = '';
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      }).catch((error: any) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
      });
  }
```

When I checked the server side,the request does not contain "users" parameter. However, if I sent it like;

```
users: JSON.stringfy(this.user_list)
```

I am able to see it on request but I need it as list not a string. So, is there any way to send it as list?

Comment: And what should it look like? You need to transform it into a correct json.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sakuto mentioned in his comment above, you need to serialize your params object into valid JSON:

```
let params = {
  fileName: filename,
  users: this.user_list,
  name: this.event_name,
  event_type: this.event_type,
  date: this.date,
  start: this.timeStarts,
  location: this.location,
  info: this.description
}

...
params: JSON.stringfy(params)
...
```

On the server, you'll need to deserialize params using the appropriate JSON utility method for your tech stack. E.g. for Node:

```
params = JSON.parse(params);
```